# How to get the emgucv compiled on my Ubuntu 18.04? It is said to support Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, emgucv

First I am not very familiar with C++ compile process, but I have to compile the [**emgucv repository**](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv) on Ubuntu 18.04. I follow the instruction and try to figure out things by searching through Stack Exchange.

I got every dependencies setup, then the only file I need to execute is [**this**](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/tree/master/platforms/ubuntu/16.04/cmake_configure.sh) one.

Although it is written for `16.04`, seems to work for `18.04`, but the compilation throws an error. It says `_MAX_DRIVE, _MAX_DIR, _MAX_PATH, DWORD, errno_t`, etc. are not declared. As suggested by the comment, they are Windows-specific. The [**error occurs in this**](https://github.com/emgucv/tesseract/blob/1f977fcca53f37b579dcc0ad10a67994ca5320f1/src/ccutil/mainblk.cpp) file. And the [**module that contains this file is this**](https://github.com/emgucv/tesseract/tree/1f977fcca53f37b579dcc0ad10a67994ca5320f1).

> **My question is** how to get this compiled on Ubuntu 18.04? I am very confused, since **Emgucv says they support Linux** (instruction at the end), and I believe others could have successfully compiled it on their Linux. I attempted to replace those constants `_MAX_DRIVE, _MAX_DIR, _MAX_PATH` by just numbers, the `DWORD` by `unsigned long`, and `errno_t` by `int`, then it says now `GetModuleFileName, _splitpath_s` are not declared. I don't know how to do. Is there anyway for this to work for Ubuntu?

```
[ 74%] Building CXX object Emgu.CV.Extern/tesseract/libtesseract/CMakeFiles/tesseract_ccutil.dir/tesseract-ocr.git/src/ccutil/mainblk.cpp.o
/media/philips_cpm/data1/emgucv/Emgu.CV.Extern/tesseract/libtesseract/tesseract-ocr.git/src/ccutil/mainblk.cpp: In member function ‘void tesseract::CCUtil::main_setup(const char*, const char*)’:
/media/philips_cpm/data1/emgucv/Emgu.CV.Extern/tesseract/libtesseract/tesseract-ocr.git/src/ccutil/mainblk.cpp:77:16: error: ‘_MAX_DRIVE’ was not declared in this scope
     char drive[_MAX_DRIVE];
                ^~~~~~~~~~
/media/philips_cpm/data1/emgucv/Emgu.CV.Extern/tesseract/libtesseract/tesseract-ocr.git/src/ccutil/mainblk.cpp:78:14: error: ‘_MAX_DIR’ was not declared in this scope
     char dir[_MAX_DIR];
              ^~~~~~~~
/media/philips_cpm/data1/emgucv/Emgu.CV.Extern/tesseract/libtesseract/tesseract-ocr.git/src/ccutil/mainblk.cpp:79:15: error: ‘_MAX_PATH’ was not declared in this scope
     char path[_MAX_PATH];
               ^~~~~~~~~
/media/philips_cpm/data1/emgucv/Emgu.CV.Extern/tesseract/libtesseract/tesseract-ocr.git/src/ccutil/mainblk.cpp:83:5: error: ‘DWORD’ was not declared in this scope
     DWORD length = GetModuleFileName(nullptr, path, sizeof(path));
     ^~~~~
/media/philips_cpm/data1/emgucv/Emgu.CV.Extern/tesseract/libtesseract/tesseract-ocr.git/src/ccutil/mainblk.cpp:85:9: error: ‘length’ was not declared in this scope
     if (length > 0 && length < sizeof(path)) {
         ^~~~~~
/media/philips_cpm/data1/emgucv/Emgu.CV.Extern/tesseract/libtesseract/tesseract-ocr.git/src/ccutil/mainblk.cpp:85:39: error: ‘path’ was not declared in this scope
     if (length > 0 && length < sizeof(path)) {
                                       ^~~~
/media/philips_cpm/data1/emgucv/Emgu.CV.Extern/tesseract/libtesseract/tesseract-ocr.git/src/ccutil/mainblk.cpp:86:7: error: ‘errno_t’ was not declared in this scope
       errno_t result = _splitpath_s(path, drive, sizeof(drive),
       ^~~~~~~
/media/philips_cpm/data1/emgucv/Emgu.CV.Extern/tesseract/libtesseract/tesseract-ocr.git/src/ccutil/mainblk.cpp:88:11: error: ‘result’ was not declared in this scope
       if (result == ERANGE) {
           ^~~~~~
/media/philips_cpm/data1/emgucv/Emgu.CV.Extern/tesseract/libtesseract/tesseract-ocr.git/src/ccutil/mainblk.cpp:92:17: error: ‘drive’ was not declared in this scope
       datadir = drive;
                 ^~~~~
/media/philips_cpm/data1/emgucv/Emgu.CV.Extern/tesseract/libtesseract/tesseract-ocr.git/src/ccutil/mainblk.cpp:93:18: error: ‘dir’ was not declared in this scope
       datadir += dir;
                  ^~~
Emgu.CV.Extern/tesseract/libtesseract/CMakeFiles/tesseract_ccutil.dir/build.make:302: recipe for target 'Emgu.CV.Extern/tesseract/libtesseract/CMakeFiles/tesseract_ccutil.dir/tesseract-ocr.git/src/ccutil/mainblk.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [Emgu.CV.Extern/tesseract/libtesseract/CMakeFiles/tesseract_ccutil.dir/tesseract-ocr.git/src/ccutil/mainblk.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5929: recipe for target 'Emgu.CV.Extern/tesseract/libtesseract/CMakeFiles/tesseract_ccutil.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [Emgu.CV.Extern/tesseract/libtesseract/CMakeFiles/tesseract_ccutil.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

[**Emgu CV compile manual for Ubuntu**](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#Ubuntu_16.04)

**The commands are summarized below**

```
git clone https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv emgucv 

cd emgucv

git submodule update --init --recursive

cd platforms/ubuntu/16.04

./apt_install_dependency.sh

./cmake_configure.sh
```

Comment: The errors shouldn't have anything to do with C++11. The errors are because many Windows-specific symbols aren't declared or defined. Perhaps it's because a missing header file for Linux builds of the library (to enable Windows compatibility)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks I edited the question. I am confused as they say they support Ubuntu and they do not mention anything about installing extra headers or something. Is there anyway for Ubuntu to recognize those Windows symbols on Ubuntu?

Comment: @RalphB.: That doesn't make sense. Even if Ubuntu somehow would recognize the _symbol_ `MAX_DRIVE`, it still wouldn't have 26 drives like Windows does. [edit] Seems like the problem is due to bad style in emgucv; really not impressed with that code.