# I have built Emgucv on Ubuntu, then what is next step?

Tags: ubuntu, emgucv

This is a follow-up question for my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527694/how-to-get-the-emgucv-compiled-on-my-ubuntu-18-04-it-is-said-to-support-ubuntu). It turns out the bad file is not important, and I bypassed the "windows symbol" issue by replacing them by equivalent Linux ones if possible.

I have finished compiling EmguCV on Ubuntu 18.04 by running the script /platform/ubuntu/16.04/cmake_configue.sh

I am not sure, but I think the instruction in http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation for Ubuntu seems outdated. The above script seems to complete all the build. There is no make file in the root folder.

Now, I don't know what is next step. The situation is totally different from the official instruction. There is no "bin" folder in the root folder. There is a "bin" folder in the "/platform/Ubuntu/16.04/build" and it consists of all ".a" files. I cannot find the compiled examples, I cannot find those "Dlls", and my mono C# program using EmguCV still complains about "DllNotFoundException" occurrs in cvextern.

What is on the instruction
[image: ![enter image description here]

What is in the build folder
[image]

What is in the bin folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The wiki indeed seems to be out of date. The

```
./cmake_configure
```

line calls a script that calls `make` so you don't have to. After it ran, I ran the commands

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and

```
make install
```

This placed a file called libcvextern.so in the directory usr/local/libs (I did not find the dlls listed in the wiki, but this seemed to work in their place). I did not find examples either, but I had a .net application with an EmguCV dependency that I was trying to run. I copied the libcvextern.so file into the bin directory of the .net application and it ran successfully.